# Magento Widget doesn't appear on frontend

Tags: magento2, frontend, widget

I have created a simple widget which displays dummy data. The problem is my front end code doesn't show up in my page ? I 'm working on Magento 2.2.0.

Here is my widget code what i want to display :

```
{{widget type="Widget\CustomWidget\Block\Widget\ContactInformations" fullname="Adrien" gender="mal" age="24"}}
```

widget/contact_informations code :

```
<?php
$fullname = $this->getData('fullname');
$age = $this->getData('age');
$gender = $this->getData('gender');
?>
<ul>
    <?php if($fullname !=''){?>
    <li><?php echo $fullname; ?></li>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php if($age !=''){?>
    <li><?php echo $age; ?></li>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php if($gender!=''){?>
    <li>

    </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

etc/module.xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Widget_CustomWidget" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

etc/widget.xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widgets xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Widget:etc/widget.xsd">
    <widget id="widget_customwidget" class="Widget\CustomWidget\Block\Widget\ContactInformations">
        <label translate="true">Contact Informations Widget</label>
        <description>Widget in Magento2</description>
        <parameters>
            <parameter name="fullname" xsi:type="text"  visible="true" sort_order="0" >
                <label translate="true">Full Name</label>
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="age" xsi:type="text"  visible="true" sort_order="10" >
                <label translate="true">Age</label>
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="gender" xsi:type="select" source_model="Widget\CustomWidget\Model\Config\Source\Gender" visible="true" sort_order="10" >
                <label translate="true">Gender</label>
            </parameter>
        </parameters>
    </widget>
</widgets>
```

Widget/CustomWidget/Block/Widget/ContactInformations code :

```
<?php
namespace Widget\CustomWidget\Block\Widget; 
class ContactInformations extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template implements \Magento\Widget\Block\BlockInterface
{
    public function _toHtml()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('widget/contact_informations.phtml');
    }
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: You should post your custom widget code here?

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: can you show the code for `Widget\CustomWidget\Block\Widget\ContactInformations` ? is it extending `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` or other widget block?

Comment: Question updated @MiroslavPetroff

Comment: @AdrienCastagliola   instead of using _toHtml() ,  Use   _construct function it will work - try this code - 
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
         $this->setTemplate('widget/contact_informations.phtml');
    }

Comment: I tried your code @ManthanDave , unfortunately my template is not showing.

Comment: @AdrienCastagliola I have tried your code and it works for me just  i have change public function_toHtml to protected function _construct() also Please confirm ? your template is loading(if i pass static text then its shows ?) and only values you are not getting correct ?

Comment: I set $this->setTemplate('<h1>test</h1>'); but nothing is showing up @ManthanDave

Comment: @AdrienCastagliola Instead of that write echo "hello world"; in your template(.phtml file) and check when you display your widget is it display hello world or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49430/discussion-between-adrien-castagliola-and-manthan-dave).

Comment: try with the code of my answer @AdrienCastagliola

Answer (score 3):

Your widget block `Widget\CustomWidget\Block\Widget\ContactInformations` should extend `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` otherwise it can't be displayed.

Everything is ok in your configuration code. However your Block code is wrong. You shouldn't override _tomHtml() in this case but define your template as `protected $_template = 'widget/contact_informations.phtml'`. Your template must be stored to this path, at the root of your module:  `/view/frontend/widget/contact_informations.phtml`

```
<?php 
namespace Widget\CustomWidget\Block\Widget;

class ContactInformations extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template implements \Magento\Widget\Block\BlockInterface {

protected $_template = 'widget/contact_informations.phtml';

}
```

Comment: It already does.

Comment: <?php
namespace Widget\CustomWidget\Block\Widget; 
class ContactInformations extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template implements \Magento\Widget\Block\BlockInterface
{
    $_template = 'widget/contact_informations.phtml';
}

Comment: Try to replace your code by the code above

Comment: My code expects a function i think.

Comment: Actually your method '_toHtml' is completely wrong.. Please do not override _toHtml() and override the member class $_template with your template value.

Comment: Unfortunately I get a `parse error : expecting function ` and  `HTTP ERROR 500` .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49416/discussion-between-mr-k-and-adrien-castagliola).

Comment: @AdrienCastagliola I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your widget class should be like this:

```
<?php
namespace Widget\CustomWidget\Block\Widget; 
class ContactInformations extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template implements \Magento\Widget\Block\BlockInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function _toHtml()
    {
        $this->setTemplate("widget/contact_informations.phtml");
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }
}
```